# What does "@Override" and "<? extends Page>" mean?

Tags: java

```
@Override
public Class< ? extends Page> getHomePage() {
            return HomePage.class;
}


public Class<HomePage> getHomePage(){
        return HomePage.class;
}
```

The first one has an annotation
    Override. What does that mean or
    what does it send to the framework.

Will both the methods return the same class. I mean what does this mean  `? extends Page`. I mean the ? Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) [Override Annotation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html)

Javadoc : Indicates that a method declaration is intended to override a method declaration in a superclass. If a method is annotated with this annotation type but does not override a superclass method, compilers are required to generate an error message.

2) ? means any. for example :  < ? > means any java data type can be here

< ? extends Page > means any subclass of Page is allowed here.

Answer (score 2):

[JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html)

Comment: It would have been better to provide some information directly, together with the link.

Answer (score 2):

`@Override`—

> the @Override annotation informs the compiler that the element is meant to override an element declared in a superclass (overriding methods will be discussed in the the lesson titled "Interfaces and Inheritance").

**Also See**

- [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html)
- [when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why)

Comment: Expanding on this a bit, it'll give you a neat underlined error in IDE's indicating you're not actually overriding (or implementing) a method in a superclass or interface. This'll help with, for example, typos (writing a method 'getHomPage()', which wouldn't give any error messages, just odd behavior as it seems your own getHomePage() method won't get executed).

Comment: @Cthulhu IDE gets this info from compiler only, and use this is true usage of `@Override` , check updated answer

Answer (score 2):

And to the second question: [a wildcard](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

Both methods will return the same object (the `Class` instance representing `HomePage`), but they are declared in different ways, allowing the wild-carded version to be used by methods that don't care what kind of `Page` you have, as long as it's a subclass of `Page`.